# Push notification for NEW rss feed?

Tags: android, rss, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How i can send push notification with new rss feed? 
I have developed a RSS feed application for my website and its working only i need push notification when a new rss update.
Is there any way how I can automatically check for new feeds in RSS xml link and send a push notification regarding the new feed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a billion options you know:

1. push the notification as you inserting the data (RSS).
2. Write a script that runs on a cron job and check for new feeds then push the notification.

Option **#1** is better in my opinion. but when you have to many apps doing the `INSERT` and you have not designed your apps to implement the push notification from the beginning than you left with option **#2**

---

- [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)
- [Create a project](https://console.developers.google.com/project)

Comment: can you help me for Option #1 ?

Comment: @user2973472 you said `when a new rss update` thats when you push the notification

Comment: but how i can do this? i mean i have a code for my app that is working and display me all rss feed in my app.. now i want that when my new rss feed update. my app show me with push notification!

Comment: who is creating the `RSS` feed, you?

Comment: yeah (through my website )

Comment: Ok, start [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) you need to implement GCM client, basically it is a service that will listen for push notification. Now your server (which is hosting the website) is responsible to push the notification as you are updating the RSS

Comment: i also have to implement something for server?

Comment: what is your opinion if i will do this with my json data.. is it more easy?

Comment: Yes you need to post to google server the playload (push alert data) actually the playload is in JSON format so you should be good. Its just a matter of posting data to google server. check here http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#payload

Comment: first i want to try with rss feed ! because i have done app which show me all rss feed...

Comment: yeah There are many ways to achieve this depending on the langague you're using to code

Comment: i used this [code](http://www.itcuties.com/android/android-asynctask-rss-reader/)

Comment: this code work correctly , now i need for push notification , but i don't know how? :(

Comment: Create a project https://console.developers.google.com/ then read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html), it easy to follow. when you get stuck post a question again.there are also tutorials but make sure they are not outdated.

Comment: yes, I have project (Api access) ...now i have to start implement gcm client right?

Comment: yes, the good news is the documentation has all the code, so you dont have to write that code ;). just copy paste it. and follow everything

Comment: Just i have to copy paste all the code in my project app right?

Comment: If I answered your questions you can mark this as accepted. Then ask more question as you progress with your implementation ;). Good luck bro

Comment: lol sure, you can put the link to your new question here in the comments. there also many smart folks out there ;)